# Error in c programming text file structure and fgets

Tags: c

My program is not responding and I need input like below.
This my text file:

```
MU-547 China Eastern      10.55       1.20    Every day, via Shianghai + 1 day 
MU-541 China Eastern      13.50       1.20    Every day, via Shianghai + 1 day 
CI-835 China Airlines     9.40        16.00   Every day, via Taipei
CI-065 China Airlines     16.25       1.10   Every day, via Taipei
SQ-970 Singapore Airlines 20.50       8.40    Every day, via singapore  
SQ-972 Singapore Airlines 20.50       11.05   Every day, via singapore  
SQ-974 Singapore Airlines 20.50       14.35   Every day, via singapore  
SQ-976 Singapore Airlines 20.50       17.55   Every day, via singapore  
SQ-978 Singapore Airlines 20.50       20.05   Every day, via singapore  
CX-751 Cathay Pacific     9.15        16.20   Every day, via Hong Kong
CX-701 Cathay Pacific     10.45       17.55   Every day, via Hong Kong
```

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct 
{
  char id[7];
  char airlineName[31];
  float arrive,depart;
  char notes[100];
} AIRLINE;

void openFile(const char *data2)
{
  AIRLINE plane[12] = {0};
  int i = 0;
  FILE *file = fopen(data2, "r");
  if (file)
  {
    char line[83];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) && i < 6)
    {
      fputs(line, stdout); 
      if(sscanf(line,
                "%6s %30c%f%f%99c",
                plane[i].id,
                plane[i].airlineName,
                plane[i].arrive,
                plane[i].depart,
                plane[i].notes) == 5)
      {
        printf(" %s ", plane[i].id);
        printf(" %c ", plane[i].airlineName);
        printf(" %f ", plane[i].arrive);
        printf(" %f ", plane[i].depart);
        printf(" %c ", plane[i].notes);
        i++;
      }         
    }
    fclose(file);
  }
  else
    perror(data2);
}

int main(void)
{
  openFile("data2.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess your `line[83]` is to small. Change it to something larger.

Comment: nsilent22 is correct. Your longest lines are over 90 chars.
Does it simply not respond?
Are you familiar with a debugger? Did you step through to see how far it gets?
Error messages - not just for debugging - would be good. e.g. If sscanf doesn't return the expected number of assignments made.

Comment: Why did you pick '83'?  Next time you need a text buffer, (and you are not developing for a RAM-restricted embedded system), just use [256] as a minimum for all buffers.  If devs did that, there would be fewer SO posts for buffer overruns, especially those annoying obi-wans where the dev. did not leave space for the null-terminator.

Comment: Unless clear rules exist for input file, like _no more than 83 characters allowed per line_, or _no more than 12 lines allowed per input file_, or _no more than 31 characters allowed for an [airline name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes-A)_, etc., you will have problems reading your data in.  Your debugger is your friend.  Turn it on and let it direct you.  But also, consider the range of possibilities for an input file, and create code to accommodate them before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scanning for float with %f the address of the variable is needed and there are missing & for those values.
Scanning with %c will not terminate the variable with a '\0' and printf can then be a problem.
The format "%6s %30[^0-9]%f%f %99[^\n]" will scan up to six characters then scan up to 30 characters that are not digits, then scan two floats and finally up to 99 characters stopping at a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    char id[7];
    char airlineName[31];
    float arrive,depart;
    char notes[100];
} AIRLINE;

void openFile(const char *data2)
{
    AIRLINE plane[12] = {{{0}}};
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(data2,"r");
    if ( file )
    {
        char line[83];
        while( i < 6 && fgets(line,sizeof line, file))
        {
            fputs(line, stdout);
            if( sscanf(line,"%6s %30[^0-9]%f%f %99[^\n]",
                plane[i].id,
                plane[i].airlineName,
                &plane[i].arrive,       // needed &
                &plane[i].depart,       // needed &
                plane[i].notes) == 5 )
            {
                printf(" %s ",plane[i].id);
                printf(" %s ",plane[i].airlineName);  // use %s for string
                printf(" %f ",plane[i].arrive);
                printf(" %f ",plane[i].depart);
                printf(" %s ",plane[i].notes);
                i++;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        perror(data2);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    openFile("data2.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the statement: `char line[83];` is not large enough to contain some of the lines shown in your input file, resulting in *[buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)*.   likewise, some of the fields in your `struct` are hard coded to lengths that may not be large enough to contain what future input files *may* hand you.  ( For example, some of the airline names in *[this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes-A)* are longer than 31 characters, and will not fit into `char airlineName[31]` )  Fields like `arrive`, `depart` are probably safe using `float` types.  But the fields `notes`, `airlines` and even `id` are at least in question.  You may also *not* know the number of lines in your input file.

You can address input file line length or number of lines several ways.  Two options come immediately to mind:

***1)*** Make an estimate of line lengths, and number of lines, and hope
they are stable for each input file. (as you have seen, this has
consequences)
***2)*** determine number of lines, and max line lengths as
a *preprocessing step*, then use that information to create
appropriately sized input line char buffer, and using pointer to
struct, create space enough to contain data in each line of data,
regardless of how many lines input file contains.

For example, create a function to determine the count of lines in the file, and length of the longest line in the file, then use that information to create memory sufficient to read file line by line without risk of buffer overflow:

```
int longestline(const char *filename, int *lc)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int cnt=0, cntKeep=0;
    char c;
    (*lc) = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!fp) return 0;
    while ( (c = fgetc ( fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        if(c != '\n') 
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        else 
        {
            cnt = 0;
            (*lc)++; //update line counter
        }
        cntKeep = cntKeep < cnt ? cnt : cntKeep;//update longest line counter
    }
    if(cnt > 0) (*lc)++;//last line may not have '\n'
    fclose(fp);
    return cntKeep;
}
```

Usage example:

```
int line_cnt = 0;
int longestLine = longestline("c:\\inputfile.txt", &line_cnt)//determine longest line of file.
//char line[83];
char *line = calloc(longestLine + 1, 1);//create buffer to accommodate longest of lines found in file
//AIRLINE plane[12] = {0};
AIRLINE *plane = calloc(line_cnt, sizeof(AIRLINE));
```

This same *preprocessing* approach can also extend to creating appropriately sized struct member variables sizes as well.  Determine longest field lengths, member by member by using a similar approach expanded to use the *[strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* and *[fgets()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)* function on each line, and tracking longest length of each field as you read through the file.